# rgb percentage value conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have binded `input type="range"` with range from 0-255 and `input type="number"` with range from 0-100 values binded. The idea is to convert values from `input type="range"` to percentage in `input type="number"`. The problem is when I am using algorithm to convert `Math.round((model/255)*100)` it literally converts everything (when i'm writing, it dynamically converts my values, when i'm using this "arrows" in `input type="number"` aswell).

```
$('#element' +' input').bind('input', function(){
    var model=$(this).val();
    $('#element'+ ' .rangeInput').val(model);
    $('#element'+ ' .percentageInput').val(Math.round((model/255)*100));
});
```

Is it possible to make that kind of conversion with `input type="number"` that has `step="1"`(for this arrows on right side of input) and won't convert dynamically while on focus `number` input? Because the more i write in this input, the lower the number gets and it continues untill it reaches nearly 0.

Comment: Please share a working fiddle for your code. That would help us understand the problem better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xnehel/c9qagq5j/ originally range slider is converting to percentage perfectly, but the only problem are the arrows in `input type="number"`, whenver you click either the upper or bottom it will always make it value/255 * 100

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but is this what your are looking for [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/c9qagq5j/1/)

Comment: Naaah, i want `$('.percentageInput').val((model/255)*100)` to work properly when using arrows that are in `input type="number"`, in css they are called `input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button`, and i would like to have them scaling by 1, not by calculating the current value with (value/255)*100)

Comment: Actually, the fact that you mentioned in your fiddle this `(value/100*255)` (not value/255*100) helped me to solve this problem -> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPJdzN where values: left input box 0-255, middle is in % (0-100) and slider is 0-255